# NodeJS Subdomain w/ vhost and greenlock-express

Tags: node.js, express, https, vhosts, greenlock

I'm new to Node and I want my website, [dacio.app](https://dacio.app), working with subdomains for my college projects using [vhost](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vhost).

However, I need to have it secured due to the requirement for .app domains, so I'm using [greenlock-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/greenlock-express) to automate it.

> Don't be frontin', yo! TLS SNI 'giphy.dacio.app' does not match 'Host:
>   potatoes.dacio.app'

I've tried using the [vhost example](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js/src/commit/efd7693dcd9622bae768658066f55cff17bc2605/examples/vhost.js) in the [repo](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js), but it doesn't look like [server-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static) supports [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) apps.

---

Any tips on how to get this working? I keep hearing about reverse proxies, but I'm not sure if it's worth the effort as I don't even know if it would work - would it help?

### server.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

// DEPENDENCIES
const express = require('express');
const vhost   = require('vhost');
const path    = require('path');
const glx     = require('greenlock-express');

// MIDDLEWARE
const app = express();
const giphyApp = require('../giphy-search');
const potatoesApp = require('../rotten-potatoes');
const portfolioApp = require('../dacio.app');

// ROUTES
app.use(vhost('giphy.dacio.app', giphyApp));
app.use(vhost('potatoes.dacio.app', potatoesApp));
app.use(portfolioApp);

// GREENLOCK for HTTPS
glx.create({
    version: 'draft-11',
    server: 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory',
    email: 'dacioromero@gmail.com',
    agreeTos: true,
    approveDomains: [ 'dacio.app', 'giphy.dacio.app', 'potatoes.dacio.app' ],
    configDir: '~/.config/acme/',
    app: app,
    communityMember: false
}).listen(80, 443);
```

Comment: That error message appears when a particular type of attack known as “domain fronting” is being performed. The way the attack works is that you connect to the tls server with one domain name, but then switch domains at the http layer. Do you have any idea how that would be happening in your case?

Comment: Here’s a video demonstrating how to perform the attack: https://youtu.be/aZgVqPzoZTY?list=PLZaEVINf2Bq_lrS-OOzTUJB4q3HxarlXk

Comment: @CoolAJ86 I think it might be a problem related to Firefox and Chrome because it works just fine with Safari.I think It might be an optimization because my A records in my DNS settings are the same.

Comment: That sounds strange to me. Google App Engine and AWS block domain fronting by default, IIRC, so I don't see why a browser would do it for optimization. Are there any other details you can share? Did you get it working?

Comment: That whole thing was just a guess that I wasn't even convinced of myself. 
All of the A Records point to the same IP, my server is running CentOS 7, /etc/hosts is unmodified, and the source for the subdomains is on [my GitHub](https://github.com/DacioRomero).
Thanks for spending the time to try to figure this out, I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've switched to using [redbird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redbird) which seems to accomplish everything I was hoping to do.

```
const path = require('path')

const proxy = require('redbird')({
    port: 80,
    letsencrypt: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/certs'),
        port: 9999
    },
    ssl: {
        http2: true,
        port: 443
    }
});

proxy.register('dacio.app', 'http://localhost:8080', {
    ssl: {
        letsencrypt: {
            email: 'dacioromero@gmail.com',
            production: true,
        }
    }
});

proxy.register('giphy.dacio.app', 'http://localhost:8081', {
    ssl: {
        letsencrypt: {
            email: 'dacioromero@gmail.com',
            production: true
        }
    }
})

proxy.register('potatoes.dacio.app', 'http://localhost:8082', {
    ssl: {
        letsencrypt: {
            email: 'dacioromero@gmail.com',
            production: true
        }
    }
});
```